# automatic scroll - a scroll view on Touch of textField - iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have many textfields in my Application which are in a scrollview.

What i need is when user touches on a textfield,

scrollview should scroll in such a way, so that that textfield should not be behind
the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method - `(void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated` in UIScrollView, this should scroll to the offset of the point you give it, you will need to figure out the offset through code

Answer (score 2):

I've written a pretty straightforward tutorial on doing this, it mimics as much as possible the behavior of Apple own applications, if it can be of any help:

[Adjust UITextField hidden behind Keyboard with UIScrollView](http://www.iphonesampleapps.com/2009/12/adjust-uitextfield-hidden-behind-keyboard-with-uiscrollview/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could set the text fields' delegates to self, and then adopt the UITextFielDelegate protocol for the class, and then in this method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Make the scroll view scroll down enough so that you can see the text field.. I don't know how to make the scrollview scroll down though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a free library for keyboard handling http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/509810/Keyboard-Handling-in-iPhone-Applications. You need write just one line of code:

```
[AutoScroller addAutoScrollTo:scrollView];
```

Dont confuse with name AutoScroller. Purpose is same what you asked.